# Git: remove unwanted untracked files from branch

Tags: git, merge

I updated my branch from master and have a few files that were deleted on master, but remain on my local and appear as untracked files. I want to remove these files - ie confirm I don't want them on my local anymore.

I've tried `git rm <file>` but this does nothing - no message and no changes when I run `git status`.

I've tried checking out the files from master (`git checkout -- <file>`) but of course I get a message saying the file doesn't exist on master.

I've tried running `git clean -n` but I get a lot of messages saying `Would not remove <file>`.

I also tried deleting the branch `git branch -D <branch-name>` and pulling in a fresh version, but still get the same merge conflicts.

Would anyone know what I can do?

Comment: delete them in the filesystem?

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

This question does not seem to make sense.  Untracked files are already not there, so there is nothing to remove.  More precisely, an *untracked file* is a file that is in the work-tree, but not in the index.  As such, Git just lets it sit there, and *mostly* ignores it, except for two things:

- Git keeps whining about it being untracked, in `git status` output for instance.
- Running `git add` with any option that means "add everything", such as `git add .`, will add it *to* the index, so that it is now tracked.

To stop both of these annoying cases, people list particular untracked file names or name-patterns in `.gitignore` files.  Note that `.gitignore` does not *cause* a file to *become* untracked; it just shuts up Git about the file clutttering up the work-tree, and makes sure that "add all" skips that file.

#### Long

An *untracked file* is a file that is not in the index.  The index is its own independent thing: it's not a branch and it's not a work-tree.  Instead, it's the place where you build the *next* commit that you intend to make, by *staging* updated files.  This is why it is sometimes called the *staging area*.  It also has the effect of indexing  and *caching* the work-tree, hence its name *index*, and a third name, the *cache*.

Note that the index is a sort of live thing: its contents change over time, especially as you check out particular commits, or go to create new ones.  In any case, though, the index is not part of a branch, so "remove untracked files from a branch" makes no immediate sense.  But we also need to pin down what *you* mean by "branch" here: see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

Note that a *branch name* points to one specific commit.  If you run `git checkout name`, you are checking out the specific commit to which the name *`name`* points.  The act of checking out a commit *fills in* the index, so now the index contains some set of files, and *now* we can talk about whether some file is or is not in the index, and hence is or is not untracked.  (The word *untracked* appears more often than *tracked*, but it seems clear enough that a *tracked file* is one that *is* in the index.)

If, after `git checkout name`, some path *P* is tracked, running `git rm P` followed by `git commit` will make a *new* commit, and change *`name`* so that it identifies this new commit.  This new commit will be one that, when checked out, leaves *P* *out* of the index, removing it from the index if necessary.  So now *`name`* identifies a commit that has path *P* untracked.  If that's what you meant by "branch" above, then this is your answer.

On the other hand, if you meant the word "branch" to encompass *all commits reachable from* the name, or something along those lines, you have a much tougher problem.  You cannot change any existing commit at all.  You can make a series of new commits, that you consider somehow "better" than the originals: for instance, you can make a series of new commits, none of which have path *P* in them, and then stop using all the old commits and begin using only these new commits instead.  This is what many call *rewriting history:* changing the set of commits identified by some branch name(s) so that those new-and-improved commits are different from all the original commits.  The downside to this kind of history rewriting is that you must get *all* users of clones of these repositories to switch *all* their usage to the new commits; otherwise the old commits just keep coming back, like a bad case of some sort of terrible disease.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried running git clean -n but I get a lot of messages saying Would not remove .

`-n` means `dry-run`, i.e **Don’t actually remove anything, just show what would be done.**, The message just tell you this fact.

If you want to delete untracked file, you should use command `git clean -dxf`

Quatation from manpage of `git clean`

> -d
>
> Remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files. If an untracked directory is managed by a different git repository, it is not removed by default. Use -f option twice if you really want to remove such a directory.
>
> -f, --force
>
> If the git configuration variable clean.requireForce is not set to false, git clean will refuse to run unless given -f or -n.
>
> -x
>
> Don’t use the standard ignore rules read from .gitignore (per directory) and $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, but do still use the ignore rules given with -e options. This allows removing all untracked files, including build products. This can be used (possibly in conjunction with git reset) to create a pristine working directory to test a clean build.